# Как сделать так, чтобы sticky-блок не пропадал?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

Как сделать так, чтобы sticky-блок не пропадал при достижении им `#support-section`, а закреплялся на конечном положении, до того момента, пока пользователь не начнет скроллить обратно выше по странице?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
      console.log( "document ready!" );

      var $sticky = $('.flying-form');
      var $stickyrStopper = $('#support-section');
      if (!!$sticky.offset()) { // make sure ".sticky" element exists

        var generalSidebarHeight = $sticky.innerHeight();
        var stickyTop = $sticky.offset().top;
        var stickOffset = 0;
        var stickyStopperPosition = $stickyrStopper.offset().top;
        var stopPoint = stickyStopperPosition - generalSidebarHeight - stickOffset;
        var diff = stopPoint + stickOffset;

        $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
          var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number

          if (stopPoint < windowTop) {
              $sticky.css({ position: 'absolute', top: diff });
          } else if (stickyTop < windowTop+stickOffset) {
              $sticky.css({ position: 'fixed', top: stickOffset });
          } else {
              $sticky.css({position: 'absolute', top: 'initial'});
          }
        });

      }
    });
```

```css
.wrapper {
}
.flying-form {
  background-color: darkred;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
#support-section {
  height: 900px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.divider {
height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flying-form">
    
  </div>
</div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div id="support-section">
  
</div>
```

Comment: пустому fixed элементу нужно задать и высоту и ширину

Comment: а чего через сам sticky не сделаешь? https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/position он будет жрать меньше ресурсов и не будет дергаться. Главное чтобы у элементов выше не было overflow